# Click on a link in repeater with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have been troubling with finding the way to click on EDIT link under particular item:

```
<li ng-repeat="item list | orderBy: predicate:false" class="ng-scope">
        <h1 class="ng-binding">item name</h1>
            <p>
                </p><div class="w140 left borderRight ng-binding">
                Contains:

                </div>

                <div class="left marginLeft20 ng-binding">
                    Last modified:
                    Dec 5, 2014
                </div>

            <p></p>

            <a href="#/f64d6673-450d-4f9c-9de8-2fa3fd29f922">edit</a>
    </li>
```

So I need to find correct item by item name and to click on the edit link. This is what I have so far but it's not finding anything:

```
 element(by.cssContainingText('.ng-binding', 'item name')).
            element(by.linkText('edit')).
            click();
```

Comment: .ng-binding class is created by angular so maybe it is not good idea to make selectors(locators) based on this class? Maybe you could try adding some different class?

Comment: But Protractor is build specifically to test Angular, why shouldn't be Angular's classes be used by Protractor ?

Comment: xpath is working:           browser.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(., 'item name')]/a")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to select 'edit' link **inside h1 element**.

Select 'edit' link **inside li element**.

```
element(by.cssContainingText('li', 'item name')).element(by.linkText('edit')).click();
```

**EDIT**

Or

```
element(by.cssContainingText('li', 'item name')).element(by.css('a')).click();
```

Comment: 'item name' was found but 'edit' was not:                                                  NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkText("edit")